# How to solve parametrically/analytically/symbolically a very complicated parametric equation which makes use of special functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{{\pi}}\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\sqrt[4]{w}\left(x-{\mu}\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{\left(x-{\mu}\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x+\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}}{2\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\sqrt[4]{w}}\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x-\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}}{2\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\sqrt[4]{w}}\right)\right)+\sqrt{2}{\sigma}^2\mathrm{e}^\frac{\left(x-{\mu}\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(x+\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}\right)^2}{4\left|{\sigma}\right|\sqrt{w}}}-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(x-\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}\right)^2}{4\left|{\sigma}\right|\sqrt{w}}}\right)}{{\sigma}\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}+b}{2\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\sqrt[4]{w}}\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\frac{v}{2}-{\mu}+{\alpha}}{2\sqrt{\left|{\sigma}\right|}\sqrt[4]{w}}\right)\right)\sqrt[4]{w}}=0$$
Is the equation and I want w expressed as a function of v, μ, σ, α and b. Special or Elementary functions are not a problem if the result(a complicated function and not a single number) has 0 partial derivative with respect to w.

This could help me define a probability mass function with finite support and probability mass at each point of its support proportional to the density at the same value of a normally distributed random variable.

I multiplied the variance of the both discrete and finite equivalent with w divided the Probability of the respective point with the Density in the same point and set the derivative to 0.

$$\dfrac{\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x-({\mu}-\frac{ν}{2})}{2\sqrt[4]{{\sigma^2w}}}\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x-({\mu}+\frac{ν}{2})}{2\sqrt[4]{{\sigma^2w}}}\right)}{\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{b-{\mu}+\frac{ν}{2}}{2\sqrt[4]{{\sigma^2w}}}\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{{α - \mu}+\frac{ν}{2}}{2\sqrt[4]{{\sigma^2w}}}\right)}$$

Is the probability mass for each value of the random variable X that belongs to its support.

Comment: Why do you believe that an inverse exists at all, much less that it can be expressed using elementary operations?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy Inverse? I want neither the inverse of any function at least I do not understand how it could help solve the equation nor the multiplicative inverse of any number. I want to solve my equation. Directly that. A goal in itself. And I also said I have no problems with Special functions. I only want to isolate w. Solve the function parametrically. I want a function as a result.

Comment: I misread slightly but the essence of my point still stands. Why do you think that a function exists, in other words why do you believe that there is a unique $w$ that satisfies that equation for every $\alpha, \mu, \nu, \sigma$?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy I do not know if such a function exists. But for the α, μ, ν, σ and b that the equation can't be satisfied α, μ, ν, σ and b could be out of the domain and the function could be undefined. Even an impossible equation has a solution. Namely no solutions. Also we could also exclude the impossible values of α, μ, ν, σ and b.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy Also I did not understand what you meant with unique w a parametric function is a family of functions and I would be satisfied with any family of functions as a result. I am not looking for a "unique" number a "unique" function but rather a whole family of functions like the one solving differential equations.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy What did you mean with "unique w"?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy What can one actually ingore safely without losing any information and thence some solution? e.g The denominator. Will it help to use any integral properties?